# Is it safe to remove python2 in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python

I had Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for a long time because I was thinking to use Kail Linux, but I never got to installing it so I just got Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Now I want to know if its safe to remove python2 because now I have python 3.6 and I when I code in python its still uses python2. And if it's not safe to remove python2 then is there a way to just make Visual Studio Code use python3.

Comment: The linked answer is the wrong way to use python3 in VS Code. For configuring VS Code's python environment, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments and configure the interpreter to be /usr/bin/python3. As I understand, it should use python3 by default anyway, though.

Comment: @dobey the last line of the linked answer points to the same link as you for configure VSCode's configuration. I am not a python expert. You may want to expand the comment to answer the question.

Comment: I only got python2 when I installed a couple of non-standard apps from repository that still required python2. Default install does not install python2, but other apps may need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**See for yourself safely** using apt's `--simulate` flag:

```
$ apt remove python --simulate
```

Read the proposed removals *very carefully* for applications and components that you don't want to remove.

If it turns out, after removing Py2, that you needed it after all...then it's trivial to reinstall.

**WARNING: This answer applies only to Ubuntu 18.04 and newer.** Earlier releases of Ubuntu have key components that depend upon Py2 (like apt). You may be very, very sorry if you remove Py2 in earlier releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: thank you for helping me, ill make sure to remember this.

Comment: Also how can I know that its not removing python 3 and only python 2

Comment: by the way it didnt work. Still have it.

Comment: @TECHSCHOOL200000 Perhaps you need to refresh your understanding of the term 'simulate'

Comment: I know what 'simulate' means when I removed 'simulate' and just do apt remove python, It says it deleted python but then i go into the command line, i type 'python' and it come up with " Python 2.7.15rc1..." and then the python command line, then when i type python3 its shows up with this "Python 3.6.6...". And in Visual Studio Code it stills shows up with python2.

Comment: The description of your problem seems incomplete and unclear. Consider either editing your question, or (recommended) asking a new question with complete, clear output. Follow-up questions buried in comments tend to not be noticed and rarely answered.