# Software Updater not working anymore on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, software-center

At some point the software updater vanished from the system. Now I reinstalled this package

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

but when I try to call it with

```
sudo /usr/bin/update-manager
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

**Additional information:**

```
~$ python -V
Python 3.6.8
~$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.12
```

The problem seems to be connected that I changed the default python to python3. But I want to keep python3 as the default python.

Comment: Most likely you removed python2 or did something else with python.

Comment: Yes could be the case.

Comment: If you remove python 2 from Ubuntu, lots of things stop working.

Comment: Yes I guess you are right. But can you help me to fix this problem or not?

Comment: Also, I did not remove python2 from the system. It is still there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to remove python2 in ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079025/is-it-safe-to-remove-python2-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `python -V`

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079025/is-it-safe-to-remove-python2-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts You've set python default to 3.

Comment: Yes most likely I have set my python default to python 3 - but that has NOTHING to do with my question.

Comment: `python` should report 2.x; `python3` should report 3.x. All system tools that use python (2.x) will no longer work - which include package tools.  It has everything to do with your question.  `dpkg` will still work though (just not `apt` tools).  Your fix is to undo what you did, restore `python` to run 2.x, and `python3` run python 3.x

Comment: My question is simply: How to fix the Software Updater. Either you can help, or you cannot

Comment: I gave you a link with a fix.

Comment: I do not want to remove python2. I am sorry. I was asking about the Software Updater.

Comment: Software updater need `python` to run python 2.x ; it and like `apt` package tools won't run if `python` runs 3.x  (for 16.04).  I don't know what you changed, however if you've forgotten and use commands, `history` will show what commands you've run to help jog your memory, if you used `apt` I'd log in /var/log/apt/ for your history of what you did etc...  Then reverse whatever you did.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. But how can I fix it?

Comment: You fix it this way. https://askubuntu.com/a/802144/167850 It doesn't remove python2, it makes it default back. `/usr/bin/python` is a link.

Comment: But that procedure will change the default python to python2. I do not want python2 as my default python. I want python3 as my default python.

Comment: Then you need to use another distro. `python` should always point to python2 on Ubuntu and `python3` to `python3`.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to keep python3 as default on Ubuntu 16.04, because many programs including `apt` are written in python2.

And there is absolutely no need to set python3 as default as you can run python3 apps using `python3 appname` or setting python3 in shebang.

You can set back default to python2 by running:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```